# jQuery fails on selecting with a value containing a decimal

Tags: jquery

Using the below code:

```
var value = 2.5;    
$el.find('[value=' + value + ']');
```

I receive this error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=2.5]
```

Is there anything I can do to remedy this? Is it definitely because of the `.` in the `value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes around the value if it contains a period `'.'`, so it would come out like `[value="2.5"]`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/t2MBs/)

```
var value = 2.5;    
$el.find('[value="' + value + '"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this before?

```
$el.find('[value="' + value + '"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't happen if you wrap the value in quotes:

```
$el.find("[value='" + value + "']")
```

I personally find it grotesque to quote a string with single quotes and use double-quotes within it; mostly because of the impact on readability, and even maintenance, I think, and another being that only a few language will let you 'get away with' this without explicit escaping etc. I think this way is a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your value into quotes. This will work:

```
var value = 2.5;    
$el.find('[value="' + value + '"]');
```